# Scrum job title

Tags: scrum

I know that in Scrum there is only three role, Product Owner, Scrum Master and Development Team. As a sign of change we must be important, not only understand these roles, but also start to change the job title to an homogenic form as Developer, Scrum Master and Product Owner. Maybe this is pointless, but we try to set an identity to the team, currently there is a mixture of titles and departments for the members of the same Development Team and we wan to change it. So how does an organization work this thing?  A restructure of this is part of implement scrum or this don't care?
 Thanks for your advise

Comment: Polling questions (ie. "how does your organization...") are off-topic on PMSE. Consider rewording to focus the question on a problem you are having.

Comment: I believe your questions is predicated on an assumption that may not be true. I see two questions here? 1) how should we change our job titles and 2) does scrum, with its limited roles, imply that there should be equally limited job titles.

Comment: I don't understand the question - what is it you want to know? If you're merely asking for job titles in other organizations, how will you use that information?  How would someone else use that information? PM:SE is for practical problem in project management. Perhaps I'm missing something but I'm not sure how knowing the job titles used at another organization would assist me to close projects or generate value in my organization.

Comment: I lookin for information if part of impleneting Scrum is normal take in count this kind of trivial things. i agree wich the title not is important, because it dont bring any value per se. But motivation and commintment some time start with this minimal changes, because it gave authority to the members of the organization. This is important for that reason, for the motivation it can bring, there are other way to increase the motiviantion, my question is about if someone already try this or how generally management the job title inside scrum

Answer (score 5):

Roles and job titles are distinct entities. You don't need to change job titles at all, if the jobs have not changed.

For example, it's perfectly normal to have job titles of "Java Developer" or "C++ Developer". It's also normal to have pay grade and experience titles like "Senior Java Developer". This is what you *do* in the company.

For Scrum, no matter what title you have, both a "Junior Java Developer" and a "Senior C++ developer" are a "Developer". Their seniority has no influence on how they act on the team in regard to the Scrum process. A Senior's estimation is not worth more than a Junior's estimation. A Junior's opinion on the retrospective is not worth less than a Senior's.

So job titles can stay as they were, as long as all adhere to Scrum principles and those titles match what they actually *do*. Obviously if you have a PM that now is the Scrum Master, this person may want to get his title changed. But because it's a different *job*, not because Scrum dictates job titles.

Comment: thanks for your questions, actually i think this is a trivial thing, but in some blogs i has read than is change the terminology is important as sign of we are changing the way we work, i totally agree in the fact of job title is not important, so as part of scrum it not have sence reorganize this thing?

Comment: Scrum definitely changes the way people work together and you should make sure this actually happens. No more "I'm more senior than you" or "But I'm the architect". But that's behavior, you can leave the job titles as they are as long as the behavior changes.

Comment: Small point, you mean you're a "Development Team member". Scrum members can (and typically do) come from more disciplines than software development.